# Circular Reference of View and Scalar Function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, stored-procedures, circular-reference

In my SQL Server 2012 database, I have a table `MyTable`, a view `MyView` and a scalar function `MyFun`.

The view will refer to `MyFun` as shown below:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MyView]
AS
    SELECT dbo.MyFun(Age) AS Expr1
    FROM dbo.MyTable
```

While the function will refer to `MyView`, as shown here:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFun] (@Age int)
RETURNS int
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN     
     SET @Age = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [db].[MyView]);
     RETURN (@Age + 1);
END;
```

Since `MyFun` and `MyView` will cause circular reference, which one should be created first? I cannot find any documents on this.

I made a test.

First, I export the database as a script. Then I find in the script, the function is created first, as below:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFun] (@Age int)
RETURNS int
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN     
     SET @Age = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [db].[MyView]);
     RETURN(@Age + 1);
END;
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [Name] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Age] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MyView]
AS
    SELECT dbo.MyFun(Age) AS Expr1
    FROM dbo.MyTable
GO
```

However, if I modify the script and put function creation after view creation, as below:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [Name] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Age] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MyView]
AS
    SELECT dbo.MyFun(Age) AS Expr1
    FROM dbo.MyTable
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFun] (@Age int)
RETURNS int
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN     
     SET @Age = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [db].[MyView]);
     RETURN(@Age + 1);
END;
GO
```

Then the creation of view will report the following error:

> Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MyView, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 17]
>   Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.MyFun", or the name is ambiguous.

So based on the test, for circular reference, the function should be created before the view, and the function can reference objects that have not been created yet.

But how about other objects, such as defaults, triggers, table-valued functions, stored procedures, etc. If they are circular refers to each other, then which one should be created first and which can be created later?

Comment: Read **Deferred Name Resolution** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms190686(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, Thank you very much. I read throught the article. However, it only for stored procedure. How about other objects? I cannot find similar documents for other objects.

Comment: Should be quite simple to create one of each of the listed objects and reference something that does not exist and see if you get an error or not. For table-valued functions make sure you test both types

Comment: IN SSMS disabling intellisense then creating the function followed by the view worked for me (sqlserver 2012)